# Nextjs useState is called in function "page" that is neither a React Function component

Tags: reactjs, components, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

18:27  Error: React Hook "useState" is called in function "page" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

I am created a client component in nextjs its giving me error on using useState in nextjs page component.

```
"use client";
import ComponentWrapper from "@/components/ComponentWrapper";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Input } from "@nextui-org/react";
import { Button } from "@nextui-org/react";
import { gql, GraphQLClient } from "graphql-request";

const graphcms = new GraphQLClient(
  "https://api-ap-south-1.hygraph.com/v2/clpy92k06kjx901un6pbv1k5c/master",
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Mtc0nFFQkw0w98T16B5bXO0jrU7muOkiPqmDbK4YLnEWroGkQ3RBVZ40QTtq7N9sqGa1noYYut7pmLjtQo18XEmCRg1hJb3hBq6AgaijVU5HhyEUM4cPTT-I97kHv3PFJMKxqWbUlBK8Jgj5bK-dhExgItn7hFWHDKn-lQ8a9JyTmXUgOgNGKO9OOB7X_VkBmNdH2T_OcyhfkVpziUIdbt1K_hD78DU-9A0bgnLTqnURSe4D2jSEMK9PKgtlvB6V1aE_a0YkyxSuPGyQnTSs8ymU7-UYzuVtR5WUM27JX40pizDz7vLImdYgxJUgjdzpNxzolEcdYcfkCABQ29zckoGZys96udF4vrNA5SnG2o2PCU6wwheDTjAAb_hGDxU_15Oop0QIC65On-d3f0T1IfLAZutbMfaIybiOgtNWpQKLiDd9D7gJE7nbZF85s5ltxjgiG6MRJ-PXIegN0cW_dFQVaPvNJbYPmfQ`,
    },
  }
);

const Page = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    number: "",
  });

  const CREATE_COMMENT = gql`
    mutation Contact {
      createContact(
        data: { name: "${data.name}", email: "${data.email}", number: "${data.number}" }
      ) {
        id
        name
        email
        number
      }
    }
  `;

  const formSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { createContact }: any = await graphcms.request(CREATE_COMMENT);

    const publishContact = gql`
      mutation MyMutation {
        publishContact(
          where: { id: "${createContact.id}" }
          to: PUBLISHED
        ) {
          id
          name
          email
        }
      }
    `;

    const publish = await graphcms.request(publishContact);

    // console.log(publish);
  };
  return (
    <ComponentWrapper>
      <h1 className="md:text-[3rem] font-bold">Contact Us</h1>
      <form
        action=""
        className="mt-5 space-y-3 shadow-lg rounded-xl"
        onSubmit={formSubmit}
      >
        <Input
          type="text"
          label="Name"
          variant="bordered"
          onChange={(e) => setData({ ...data, name: e.target.value })}
          value={data.name}
          className="max-w-lg"
        />
        <Input
          type="email"
          label="Email"
          variant="bordered"
          onChange={(e) => setData({ ...data, email: e.target.value })}
          value={data.email}
          className="max-w-lg"
        />
        <Input
          type="tel"
          label="Number"
          variant="bordered"
          value={data.number}
          onChange={(e) => setData({ ...data, number: e.target.value })}
          className="max-w-lg"
        />
        <Button color="primary" type="submit">
          Button
        </Button>
      </form>
    </ComponentWrapper>
  );
};

export default page;
```

Comment: your function page is normal function so if you want to use any hooks inside react component then your function should start with Cap like Page not page

page = normal function 
Page = react component
usePage = react custom hook

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not making a route but making a component which will be imported in your route `page.tsx` so name this component something like `UserLogin` and import it in your route component.